# How to use vert.x AzureADAuth?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, vert.x

In our company we try to start using oauth2.0 with our Azure AD Tenant using vue.js as frontend and vert.x services on the backend.

The idea would be that i want to

If i call our vert.x service with the jwt which we got from Azure AD i got a runtime exception saying: **"Not enough or too many segments"**. The JWT has 3 segments like expected. This is how i create the AzureADAuth:

```
    OAuth2ClientOptions opts = new OAuth2ClientOptions();
    opts.setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_JWT);
    OAuth2Auth auth = AzureADAuth.create(vertx,"{{application-id}}","{{secret}}","{{tenant-id}}", opts);
```

Inside my handler i try to authenticate:

```
    HttpServerRequest request = context.request();
    String authorization = request.headers().get(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

    String[] parts = authorization.split(" ");
    scheme = parts[0];
    token = parts[1];

    JsonObject creds = new JsonObject();
    creds.put("token_type", scheme);
    creds.put("access_token", token);

    authProvider.authenticate(creds,userAsyncResult -> {
      if(userAsyncResult.succeeded()){
          context.next();
      } else {
          context.fail(401);
      }
    });
```

So after i figured out that i need to add a jwk i tried to use the **AzureADAuth.discover** method.

My code looks like this:

```
    OAuth2ClientOptions optsDisc = new OAuth2ClientOptions();
    optsDisc.setSite("https://login.windows.net/{tenant-id}");
    optsDisc.setClientID("{application-id}");
    AzureADAuth.discover(vertx, optsDisc,res -> {
        if (res.succeeded()) {
            if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Discover succeeded.");
            }
        } else {
            log.error("Discover failed.");
        }
    });
```

Running this code causes a "Discover failed" with the following message:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input

So my question is how do i authenticate my user with my given bearer token with vert.x?

Comment: The `JWT` flow is a Google extension. For Azure you should use the `AUTH CODE` flow. Using discovery depends on your tenant, and you need the right address: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc

Comment: Thanks. I switched to AUTH_CODE and debugged discovery a bit further. Turns out i get an "Empty Input" in X509Factory when trying to use discovery

Comment: Please fill an issue detailing how you setup your app and I'll look at it this week. I only have a free Azure account so I hope this isn't specific to non free accounts...

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it with the common tenant and the graph api client-id. Same issue. I created an issue: https://github.com/vert-x3/issues/issues/438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously had a version conflict here.
I set all my dependencies to 3.6.2 and now it works. Just took me a bit to figure out how to handle the discovery and that i don't need to create a new OAuth2Auth object with AzureAdAuth after the discovery.

For future reference:

```
OAuth2ClientOptions optsDisc = new OAuth2ClientOptions();
opts.setClientID("{client-id}");
AzureADAuth.discover(vertx, opts,res -> {
if (res.succeeded()) {
//use res.result() to access the through discovery already created OAuth2Auth Object
log.debug("Discover succeeded.");
} else {
log.error("Discover failed.");
}
})
```